# MVC- How to get parameter value from get request which has parameter names including dot characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, parameters, get, asp.net-mvc-routing

In MVC, I know we can get parameters from a get request like this:

Request:

```
http://www.example.com/method?param1=good&param2=bad
```

And in controller

```
public ActionResult method(string param1, string param2)
{
   ....
}
```

But in my situation an external website sends me a get request like:

```
http://www.example.com/method?param.1=good&param.2=bad
```

And in controller  when i try to meet this request like as follow:

```
public ActionResult method(string param.1, string param.2)
{
   ....
}
```

I get build errors because of  dot in variable name. How can i get these parameters ? Unfortunately i can not ask them to change parameter names.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
    public ActionResult method()
    {
        string param1 = this.Request.QueryString["param.1"];
        string param2 = this.Request.QueryString["param.2"];

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

This will probably be your best bet:

```
/// <summary>
/// <paramref name="param.1"/>
/// </summary>
public void Test1()
{
    var value = HttpContext.Request.Params.Get("param.1");
}
```

Get the parameter from `HttpContext.Request.Params` rather than putting it as an explicit parameter

Comment: i tried this too and this also works. i dont know which one is better method but i accepted ssimeonov's answer since he replied earlier.

Comment: The **Params** property will let you access form and cookie info as well. See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Request('param.1') will let you access form and cookie info too.

Answer (score 0):

```
The Framework
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
     string param1 = context.Request.Params["param.1"];
```

Replace by
.net core 3.1

```
ControllerBase 
  ...
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
   ...

     string param1 = HttpContext.Request.Query["param.1"];
     string param2 = HttpContext.Request.Query["param.2"];
```